# Trouble understanding the solution to this double hashing problem

Tags: hash, hashtable, hash-collision, double-hashing

I am having trouble understanding the third question about double hashing at the link below

[http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/211-fa97/review/q-hash/index.html](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecburch/211-fa97/review/q-hash/index.html)

Here is the question,

> In the following, say our hash function for n is n % 20 and our second
> hash function, where applicable, is (n % 7) + 1.
>
> Say we use double hashing for collision resolution. Beginning with an
> empty hash table, we insert the following.
>
> 8 38 3 5 28 18 65 83
>
> How will the hash table look after the final insertion? If we then
> search for 48, how many of the inserted keys will we look at?

The solution on the page gives a hash table with the answer.

```
Answer:

   +----+
   | :  |
   | :  |
   +----+
 3 |  3 |
   +----+
 4 |    |
   +----+
 5 |  5 |
   +----+
 6 |    |
   +----+
 7 |    |
   +----+
 8 |  8 |
   +----+
 9 | 28 |
   +----+
10 | 83 |
   +----+
11 | 65 |
   +----+
12 |    |
   +----+
13 | 18 |
   +----+
   | :  |
   | :  |
   +----+
18 | 38 |
   +----+
19 |    |
   +----+
```

But I do not understand how the hash of 28 goes into slot 9 of the hash table.

From my understanding, when there is a collision we use the formula (h1(n) + i*h2(n)) mod m. Since 8 is hashed to slot 8 prior, we have a collision when we hash 28 since h1(28) = 8.

To resolve we use the formula above (28 % 20) + 1*((28 % 7) + 1) mod 8. Which is (8 + 1) mod 8 = 1. So I expect 28 to hash to slot 1 after collision, but the solution says it hashes to slot 9.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not `mod 8` but `mod table-size` i.e. 20 in this case.

Comment: You seem to believe that rehashing works in a way that ONLY the first few slots can be used by a rehashed item - how could that possibly work?

Comment: Ah ok, how do we know the table size is 20?

Comment: "Which is (8 + 1) mod 8 = 1. So I expect 28 to hash to slot 1 after collision, but the solution says it hashes to slot 9." - the second hash is used to calculate offsets from the first bucket identified by the first hash, so it's 8 + 1 == 9.  "i was confusing m for array size, when it is table size" - not sure what you mean there... the hash table is an array of buckets - the size is effectively the same, though it's possible for a program to allocate a larger array and only use the first 20 elements are being used for the hash table.  The "n % 20" hash hints that the array/table size is 20.

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out, i was confusing m for array size, when it is table size. Once you set m = 20 everything makes sense. Still not sure why we know m = 20 but thank you.

Comment: The 20 is (more or less) arbitrarily chosen by the programmer. Obviously there will tend to be more collisions on smaller tables but bigger tables use (and potentially waste) more memory. Often a size is chosen that is a prime number because the modulus operator then tends to produce less aliasing when calculating the hash slot to use.